# Can I implement "ShowsScrollingPlaceholders" in Grid?

Tags: gridview, datagridview, uwp, grid, cell

I am currently developing an UWP application containing a grid with an amount of thousands (up to 100k) of rows and up to about 100 columns. While swiping the grid i face the following issue.

1. when swiping quickly, the framerate of the grid is dropping extremely low - which results in a stroboscope-like effect and losing orientation within the grid.

To avoid this issues with "fast" swiping, the Microsoft UWP ListView provides a property called "ShowsScrollingPlaceholders" to define a lightweight data template avoiding the described stroboscope effect.

**Can I implement "ShowsScrollingPlaceholders" method in Grid.** Please let me share your ideas and thoughts.

Comment: Why did you want to define so many rows and columns for your Grid? The Grid control usually is used as a panel for layout. If you want to show large amount of data, you need to use other control. E.g, [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)

Comment: Thanks @XavierXie-MSFT I used datagrid and its working fine now.